# list index out of range in my if statement - python

Tags: python

I was messing around trying to figure out sorting and it said that the index was out of range in the if statement.

```
count = 0
while count < len(lst):
    if lst[count] < lst[count + 1]:
        x = lst[count]
        y = lst[count + 1]
 
        lst[count] = y
        lst[count + 1] = x
 
    count += 1
```

I tried printing the values with the same indexes and that work so I don't know what the problem is.

Here is the code for generating the list if it helps.

```
lst = []
 
while len(lst) < 100:
    num = random.randint(1, 100)

    if num not in lst:
         lst.append(num)
```

I know the sorting doesn't work yet. I'm just asking for help with the index problem.

Comment: In the last iteration of the loop `count == len(lst) - 1` which means `count + 1 == len(lst)` and there is no entry in `lst` for that index (the highest index is `len(lst) - 1`). Change your loop to `count < len(lst) - 1`

Comment: A python list of length N can be subscripted by values in the inclusive range -N to N-1

Answer (score 2):

This is because your loop reaches an interation (in this case, it's the last one) where the index number of `count + 1` will not exist.

To simplify, say we have a list of 3 characters: a, b and c.

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Let's try and run a loop to print the value of the index of `count + 1`.

```
count = 0
while count < 3:
    print(lst[count+1])
    count += 1
```

This will, supposedly, output "b" when `count` is 0, then "c" when `count` is 1, then on the last iteration, `count + 1` will be 3 which is an index that doesn't exist in our list, thus giving you the index out of range error.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

this error is because that you are accessing a index of a list, but your index is too big. At line 2, the length of the list could be 4, and count is 3. But, on line 3, you are trying to access a value with the index 4(count + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4), but there only is indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3. A method you could use to fix this problem is by replacing the while loop condition to:

```
while count < len(lst) - 1:
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its not clear what is "last" in your code.

Comment: sorry, @rnso, thats my mistake. I meant "lst".